# What to do here in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am new in rails. i started learning rails from a web source .http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

i have a problem in this tutorial in '5.7 Showing Post'. i don't know what to do here . i completed every previous tusk. so please someone help me.please go to the link and check 5.7 showing post,and see what they told to do.

in there(5.7 showing post) i confused in this "post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show . "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a show action in your posts_controller.rb:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

Also a show.html.erb file within the `posts` folder under the `view` sub directory of the Rails application. This means the application can redirect to the show action after a post has been created, utilising the `ID` parameter in your query string.